# Join two Pandas dataframes, sampling from the smaller dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

train_data="""input_example,user_id
example0.npy, jane
example1.npy, bob
example4.npy, alice
example5.npy, jane
example3.npy, bob
example2.npy, bob
"""

user_data="""user_data,user_id
data_jane0.npy, jane
data_jane1.npy, jane
data_bob0.npy, bob
data_bob1.npy, bob
data_alice0.npy, alice
data_alice1.npy, alice
data_alice2.npy, alice
"""

train_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(train_data), sep=",")
user_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(user_data), sep=",")
```

Suppose that the `train_df` table is many thousands of entries long, i.e., there are 1000s of unique "exampleN.npy" files. I was wondering if there was a straightforward way to merge the `train_df` and `user_df` tables where each row of the joined table matches on the key `user_id` but is subsampled from `user_df`.

Here is one example of a resulting dataframe (I'm trying to do uniform sampling, so theoretically, there are infinite possible result dataframes):

```
>>> result_df
    input_example        user_data   user_id
0    example0.npy   data_jane0.npy      jane
1    example1.npy    data_bob1.npy       bob
2    example4.npy  data_alice0.npy     alice
3    example5.npy   data_jane1.npy      jane
4    example3.npy    data_bob0.npy       bob
5    example2.npy    data_bob0.npy       bob
```

That is, the `user_data` column is filled with a random choice of filename based on the corresponding `user_id`.

I know one could write this using some multi-line for-loop query-based approach, but perhaps there was a faster way using built-in Pandas functions, e.g., "sample", "merge", "join", or "combine".

Comment: What is the logic for this in your result_df?
`example0.npy   data_jane0.npy      jane
example5.npy   data_jane1.npy      jane` Why can't it be `example0.npy   data_jane1.npy      jane
example5.npy   data_jane0.npy      jane`

Comment: @XXavier I was trying to suggest random sampling. So for my problem, we have multiple files which are representative of Jane, "data0" and "data1". If there are many input examples which pertain to Jane (e.g., "example5", "example0", maybe "example12" and many many more), we just randomly pick one of the profile files that are available (could be "data0" or "data1", it's a uniform random choice).

Comment: @XXavier so you are correct, both rows you've listed are totally possible options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I figured out a solution myself, it's a one-liner but conceptually it's the same as what @Rawson suggested. First, I do a left-merge, which results in a table with many duplicates. Then I shuffle all the rows to give it randomness. Finally, I drop the duplicates. If I add "sort_index", the resulting table will have the same ordering as the original table.

I'm able to use the `random_state` kwarg to switch up which user_data file is used. See here:

```py
>>> train_df.merge(user_df, on='user_id', how='left').sample(frac=1, random_state=0).drop_duplicates('input_example').sort_index()
   input_example user_id        user_data
1   example0.npy    jane   data_jane1.npy
2   example1.npy     bob    data_bob0.npy
6   example4.npy   alice  data_alice2.npy
8   example5.npy    jane   data_jane1.npy
10  example3.npy     bob    data_bob1.npy
11  example2.npy     bob    data_bob0.npy

>>> train_df.merge(user_df, on='user_id', how='left').sample(frac=1, random_state=1).drop_duplicates('input_example').sort_index()
   input_example user_id        user_data
1   example0.npy    jane   data_jane1.npy
2   example1.npy     bob    data_bob0.npy
4   example4.npy   alice  data_alice0.npy
7   example5.npy    jane   data_jane0.npy
10  example3.npy     bob    data_bob1.npy
12  example2.npy     bob    data_bob1.npy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sample by groups in `user_df` and then join that with `train_df`.
e.g.,

```
# this samples by fraction so each data is equally likely 
user_df = user_df.groupby("user_id").sample(frac=0.5, replace=True) 

    user_data           user_id
6   data_alice2.npy     alice
4   data_alice0.npy     alice
3   data_bob1.npy       bob
0   data_jane0.npy      jane
```

or

```
# this will sample 2 samples per group
user_df = user_df.groupby("user_id").sample(n=2, replace=True) 

    user_data           user_id
6   data_alice2.npy     alice
4   data_alice0.npy     alice
2   data_bob0.npy       bob
2   data_bob0.npy       bob
0   data_jane0.npy      jane
1   data_jane1.npy      jane
```

Join

```
pd.merge(train_df, user_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to merge with a sample without first merging both.  This doesn't include a multi-line for loop:

```
merged = train_df.merge(user_df, on="user_id", how="left").\
    groupby("input_example", as_index=False).\
        apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).\
            reset_index(drop=True)
```

1. merge the two together, on "user_id", only taking those that appear in the left
2. group by "input_example", assuming these will all be unique (other could group on both columns of train_df)
3. take a sample of size 1 for these
4. reset the index

Sampling second, after the merge, means that rows with the same user_id will not necessarily be the same (but sampling user_df first would result in all rows in the output dataframe with the same user_id).

Comment: Thanks, @Rawson! I posted a solution myself which is conceptually the same as yours, though I don't use "apply" to call the sample function N different times, that seems like it would be much slower on the scale of 1000+ rows. But like you said, the sampling has to be done second, after the merge. 

Comment: Yes, that's definitely more efficient.